# AutoMapper Error mapping types when mapping navigation property

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, automapper

I have a Post and Tag class, with a many-to-many relationship in a PostTag link table.

```
public class Post
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }

    public List<PostTag> PostTag { get; set; }

    public string AppUserId { get; set; }
    public AppUser AppUser { get; set; }
}

public class Tag
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set;  }
    public List<PostTag> PostTag { get; set; }
}

public class PostTag
{
    public Guid PostId { get; set; }
    public Post Post { get; set; }

    public Guid TagId { get; set; }
    public Tag Tag { get; set; }
}
```

I'm trying to create a custom mapping using AutoMapper, of PostDto as shown below:

```
public class PostDto
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("tags")]
    public List<TagDto> PostTags { get; set; }

    public UserDto User { get; set; }
}

public class TagDto
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class UserDto
{
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
}
```

Here's the query I'm running to return all Posts:

```
var posts = await _ctx.Posts
                        .Include(s => s.PostTags)
                        .ThenInclude(st => st.Tag)
                        .ToListAsync();

return _mapper.Map<List<Post>, List<>>(posts); // _mapper is injected using IMapper
```

Mapping profile:

```
CreateMap<UserDto, AppUser>()
    .ForMember(d => d.DisplayName, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.DisplayName));

CreateMap<Post, PostDto>();
    .ForMember(d=> d.User, o=>o.MapFrom(s => s.Appuser))
    .ForMember(d=> d.PostTags, o=>o.MapFrom(s=>s.PostTag));

CreateMap<PostTag, TagDto>()
    .ForMember(d => d.Id, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.Tag.Id))
    .ForMember(d => d.Name, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.Tag.Name));
```

Results in this error:

```
{
errors: "Error mapping types. Mapping types: List`1 -> List`1 System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[Domain.Post, Domain, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]] -> System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[Application.PostDto, Application, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]"
}
```

Comment: can we assume you meant AutoMapper when you said Mapster?

Comment: @NPras Yes. Apologies, I've fixed it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to be working, except for the fact that the list `Post.PostTag` is mapped to something named slightly differently in the DTO: `PostDto.PostTags`, requiring a member rule in the mapper profile:

```
CreateMap<Post, PostDto>()
    .ForMember(d=> d.PostTags, o=>o.MapFrom(s=>s.PostTag));
```

The rest looks okay, and the following just works for me:

```
List<Post> posts = ...blah
var dtos = mapper.Map<List<PostDto>>(posts);
```

See fiddle here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/99fpwg

Comment: Thanks. I determined the error was actually due to Post/PostDto's AppUser/UserDto properties and them not having custom mapping. I've updated with original post with the new mapping but its still throwing the same error. If I take out UserDto from PostDto, it works fine. What am I missing?

Comment: Fixed it. I mistakenly flipped the source/destination in CreateMap!

Comment: Is there any easy way to debug AutoMapper? I hate the fact that the error it produces is not helpful at all!